# Porque a ultima letra do meu código sai substituída por um ponto de interrogação "?"?

Tags: c#, criptografia

O professor pediu como trabalho do semestre um código em C# que criptografe um texto de um arquivo.

O código ainda não esta polido nem nada, eu estou fazendo só o bruto depois vou adicionar mais coisas, mas o meu problema é que toda vez a ultima letra do meu texto sai **`?`**.

Por exemplo:

> Boa noite > criptografa > descriptografa > Boa noit?

São dois códigos um para criptografar e o outro pra descriptografar:

Criptografar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Cript
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //declaração das variáveis
        string sDrive, sArquivo = "", sPalavra, sTexto = "",sOpcao;

        //método write escreve na tela do usuario
        Console.WriteLine("|---------------------------------------------------|");
        Console.WriteLine("| Gostaria de Criptografar Uma Mensagem ? (Sim/Não) |");
        Console.WriteLine("|---------------------------------------------------|");
        Console.Write("--->>>>>>>>");

        //Aqui é feito uma conversão, pois a opcao é inicialmente uma string
        sOpcao = Console.ReadLine();

        //PEDE VALORES DO ARQUIVO A SER CRIADO
        Console.Write("Digite em Qual driver o arquivo sera salvo: ");
        sDrive = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Digite o Nome do Arquivo(Sem a Extensão .txt): ");
        sArquivo = Console.ReadLine();

        //depois da conversão o switch verifica a opcao digitada
        if ((sOpcao == "s") || (sOpcao == "sim") || (sOpcao == "S" ) || (sOpcao == "SIM") || (sOpcao == "Sim"))
        {
            Console.Write("Entre com a mensagem para ser criptografada: ");

            //sPalavra é a variavel que o usuario vai digitar.                    
            sPalavra = Console.ReadLine();

            int[] iAscii = new int[sPalavra.Length];
            char[] cChar = new char[sPalavra.Length];

            //enquanto a palavra for menor que i
            for (int i = 0; i < sPalavra.Length; i++)
            {
                //Transforma o texto no codigo ASCII dele e retira 5 posições na tabela ASCII (para criptografar) 
                iAscii[i] = ((int)sPalavra[i]);
                iAscii[i] = iAscii[i] + 5;
                cChar[i] = ((char)iAscii[i]);
                sTexto = sTexto + cChar[i];
            }

            // Cria e Grava o Arquivo
            sArquivo = sDrive + ":" + sArquivo + ".txt";
            using (StreamWriter arquivo = File.CreateText(sArquivo))
            {
                arquivo.WriteLine(sTexto);
                arquivo.Close();
            }

            // Mostra na Tela o Arquivo Criado
            Console.WriteLine("Arquivo Criado Como: " + sArquivo);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Descriptografar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace DeCrypt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //declaração das variáveis
            string sDrive, sArquivo, sPalavra = "", sTexto = "",sOpcao;


            //método write escreve na tela do prompt do usuario
            Console.WriteLine("|---------------------------------------------------|");
            Console.WriteLine("| Gostaria de Descriptografar Uma Mensagem ? (S/N)  |");
            Console.WriteLine("|---------------------------------------------------|");
            Console.WriteLine("--->>>>>> ");

            //Aqui é feito uma conversão, pois o opcao é inicialmente uma string
            sOpcao = Console.ReadLine();

            //Aqui, A pessoa digitara o nome e o drive do arquivo
            Console.WriteLine("Letra do Drive do Arquivo Instalado: ");
            sDrive = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Digite o Nome do Arquivo(Sem Extensão): ");
            sArquivo = Console.ReadLine();
            sArquivo = sDrive + ":" + sArquivo + ".txt";

            if (!File.Exists(sArquivo))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Arquivo " + sArquivo + " não Existe." );
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O ARQUIVO DESCRIPTOGRAFADO FICOU ASSIM: ");

                // ABRE ARQUIVO TEXTO
                sPalavra = File.ReadAllText(sArquivo);
                //depois da conversão o switch verifica a opcao digitada
                switch (sOpcao)
                {
                    //caso a opcao escolhida for 2
                    case "s":
                        int[] iAscii = new int[sPalavra.Length];
                        char[] cChar = new char[sPalavra.Length];

                        //enquanto a palavra for menor que i
                        for (int i = 0; i <= sPalavra.Length; i++)
                        {
                            //Transforma o texto no codigo ASCII dele e Acrescenta 5 posições na tabela ASCII (para criptografar) 
                            iAscii[i] = ((int)sPalavra[i]);
                            iAscii[i] = iAscii[i] - 5;
                            cChar[i] = ((char)iAscii[i]);
                            sTexto = sTexto + cChar[i];
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(sTexto);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sua rotina de criptografia está funcionando, como este exemplo no dotNETFiddle pode demonstrar:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WIouyV

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string sPalavra, sTexto = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Criptografando...");

        sPalavra = "Boa noite";

        int[] iAscii = new int[sPalavra.Length];
        char[] cChar = new char[sPalavra.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sPalavra.Length; i++)
        {
            iAscii[i] = ((int)sPalavra[i]);
            iAscii[i] = iAscii[i] + 5;
            cChar[i] = ((char)iAscii[i]);
            sTexto = sTexto + cChar[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sTexto);

        Console.WriteLine("Descriptografando...");

        sPalavra = "Gtf%stnyj";
        sTexto = "";

        iAscii = new int[sPalavra.Length];
        cChar = new char[sPalavra.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sPalavra.Length; i++)
        {
            iAscii[i] = ((int)sPalavra[i]);
            iAscii[i] = iAscii[i] - 5;
            cChar[i] = ((char)iAscii[i]);
            sTexto = sTexto + cChar[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sTexto);
    }
}
```

> Criptografando...
>   Gtf%stnyj
>   Descriptografando...
>   Boa noite

O que acontece é que você está utilizando o método `TextWriter.WriteLine`, que adiciona automaticamente o marcador de fim-de-linha (`Environment.NewLine`) composto dos caracteres Carriage Return (ASCII 13) e Line Feed (ASCII 10), aumentando assim sua string de 9 para 11 caracteres (`"Boa noite"` + `CR` + `LF`).

Não tenho como testar agora, porém acho que sua rotina de leitura do arquivo está incluindo este marcador no ciclo de 'decriptação' - o que seria uma possível causa do retorno com o caracter '?'.

Comment: Mano, não tenho palavras pra descrever o quanto estou agradecido pela sua ajuda, portanto, muito obrigado !!!!

Comment: @PedroAnselmo Não por isso, é sempre um prazer ajudar! Depois nos deixe saber se você conseguiu botar seu código para funcionar. =)

Comment: @PedroAnselmo se a resposta solucionou seu problema, clique no "V" verdinho ao lado dela para marcar como aceita, assim aparece como resolvido na listagem do site, e indica a solução para futuros leitores.

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a análise do OnoSendai:

está sim incluindo uma linha indevida ao gravar no arquivo texto, após ajustar isto funcionou.

Retire também o "=" do seu loop no método de decryp, caso o contrário apresentará o erro: System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sPalavra.Length; i++)
```

Sempre que traduzir "boa noite" será o mesmo texto? Leia sobre criptografia assimétrica para deixar o seu código menos vulnerável

Comment: Perdão... esse "="nem estava no código. Essa foi uma das tentativas pra corrigir o problema e eu acabei colocando junto, mas eu descobri rapido que esse erro acontecia. Obrigado mesmo assim.